# Django and SQL. Join and group by

Tags: python, sql, django

Sorry if you dislike my question's title. I just did not know how to name it.
In short i have model.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
class Visitor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

For example there 300 Visitors From USA 120 from France 25 From Spain.
I need to get name of country and max amount how many visitors from this country?
I am not good on sql and asking this question

Is there way how to realize it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Visitor.objects.all().values('country__title').annotate(total=Count('country__title')).order_by('total')[:1]
```

try this

Comment: yeah this will give me list one after one but i need only one result? LIMIT 1?